# variable dereferancing error is not solving

Tags: java, console-application

I am trying to write a program in java which can count number of '1' in a range of numbers.

> For examples: if we look from range 1 - 20 we will get **12**  1's
>   **1**, 2,3....9, **1** 0, **1**  **1** .... **1** 9, 20.

here is the code i have written.

```
public class Count_no_of_ones
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    int count = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i<=20; i++ )
    {
      int a=i;
      char b[] = a.toString().toCharArray(); //converting a number to single digit array

      for ( int j = 0; j < b.length; j++ )
      {
        if( Integer.parseInt(b[j]) == 1 )
        {
            count++; // checking and counting if the element in array is 1 or not.
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("number of ones is : " + count);
} 

}
```

I am getting two errors on compiling.

```
D:\Programs\Java>javac Count_no_of_ones.java

Count_no_of_ones.java:10: error: int cannot be dereferenced
char b[] = a.toString().toCharArray(); //converting a number to single digit array
            ^
Count_no_of_ones.java:14: error: no suitable method found for parseInt(char)
if( Integer.parseInt(b[j]) == 1 )
           ^
method Integer.parseInt(String) is not applicable
(actual argument char cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)

method Integer.parseInt(String,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

2 errors
D:\Programs\Java>
```

Can you also explain what i did wrong in the code. i never had problem with `Integer.parseInt` and this de-referencing problem is new to me. i just heard about it in awt class but i never actually faced it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call methods on primitive types in Java. Use the static method `Integer.toString` instead:

```
char b[] = Integer.toString(a).toCharArray();
```

You also don't actually need to convert to a character array. You can index into a string using [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

---

The method `parseInt` accepts a string, not a char, so this line doesn't work:

```
if( Integer.parseInt(b[j]) == 1 )
```

Instead do the comparison with the char `'1'`:

```
if (b[j] == '1')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain why i was getting error in `Integet.parseInt`.

Comment: I need to count all the 1 in the number , eg: 1011001 has 4 1's. i don't know if charAt can help here.

Comment: @abhinav: the `parseInt()` method only accepts a `String` as argument but you were providing it a `character` via `b[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should do it for you:

```
public class Count_no_of_ones
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    int count = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i<=20; i++ )
    {
      int a=i;
      char[] b = (new Integer(i)).toString().toCharArray();


      for ( int j = 0; j < b.length; j++ )
      {
        if( b[j] == '1' )
        {
            count++; // checking and counting if the element in array is 1 or not.
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("number of ones is : " + count);
} 

}
```

Comment: @david: abhinav asked another question in a comment in mark's answer... i modified it for his requirement. Don't want to take anything from mark.